# ConstraintLayout ignores margins

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have very simple layout, which can be replaced with one RelativeLayout which always work. However wherever I put margins they are ignored and no, I don't want to use padding and no, chain also doesn't fix the problem. Any idea?

For example margins on date or manufacturer are ignored as well as others.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="?attr/szykColorSecondary"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            style="?attr/szyk_textMedium"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="16.12.2014"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/manufacturer"
            style="?attr/szyk_textBody"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="Samsung"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/model"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/date" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/model"
            style="?attr/szyk_textBody"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="S6 edge"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/manufacturer"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/manufacturer"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/delete"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/manufacturer" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_vector_delete"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/serial"
            style="?attr/szyk_textMedium"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="FDSF6D7A8FDAS6F7D89AS"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/manufacturer" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/restore"
            style="?attr/szyk_textButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:text="@string/restore"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/serial" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Version

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

Tools

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'
```

Comment: can u explain which margin..?

Comment: Any. For exampke date and msnufacturer. It's in the question...

Comment: because in my android studio it accepting margin

Comment: Ou, weird. Do you use 27 tools version?

Comment: yes `buildToolsVersion "27.0.0"` if i change marging textview moving as per margin

Comment: What version of constrsint?

Comment: `compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'`

Comment: did i show u screenshot in ans

Comment: Same as mine. But it's still not working...

Comment: you want space between date and delete?

Comment: Data and Manufacturer. Already told that 3 times ;)

Comment: @SzymonKlimaszewski your layout looks like https://imgur.com/a/evxRM if you remove marginbottom from date and just have margintop for manufacturer I don't understand the problem

Comment: For me it looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/GcRnS

Comment: My as version: https://imgur.com/YBsm6vn

Comment: @SzymonKlimaszewski did you solved it yet..?

Comment: No, I've tried different combinations of version and tools and the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, my bad. The root cause of the issue was style I've been using. It had defined `android:layout_margin`, which overrides all the more specific margins such as `android:layout_marginTop`

```
<item name="android:layout_margin">2dp</item>
```

Comment: Compnent-specific override more general onessuch as styles, as is the case with the rest of the Android components.

Comment: No, if you define layout_margin, then layout_margin_left|right|top|bottom are ignored

Comment: Apologies, this override issue is absurd but you're right. I edited the answer to add some clarification and so I could undo my downvote

Answer (score 0):

Some times preview shown result layout incorrect. However your date TextView does not contain any mention about bottom position so system don't know from what exactly position you wanna margin.

Try this edited xml.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white_transparent_50"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="16.12.2014"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/manufacturer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="Samsung"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/date" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/model"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="S6 edge"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/manufacturer"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/manufacturer"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/delete"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/manufacturer" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/serial"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="FDSF6D7A8FDAS6F7D89AS"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/manufacturer" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/restore"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:text="123123123"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/serial" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: @SzymonKlimaszewski actually i created test layout, removal CardView parent and this custom styles, checked this xml and margin is working well. So might your error isn't in this xml. And as I said try to reboot Android Studio sometimes it helps for me.

Comment: See comments on the original thread. For some people it works, not for me.

Comment: @SzymonKlimaszewski please show the result view in launched app not in layout builder